# Chisquare test on three columns in R

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, p-value, biostatistics

Usually if I have two groups and to check their association with different features I use `chisq. test` to check which is associated with features.

Lets say I have data like below:

[image]

To check the association with `stages` I do like below:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(95,55), y=c(17,14))

df
   x  y
1 95 17
2 55 14

chisq.test(df, correct = F)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  df
X-squared = 0.78587, df = 1, p-value = 0.3754
```

But now I have three Groups, Group A, B and C. I would like to check their association with features. The data looks like below:

[image]

I have applied `chisq.test` on three columns like below:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(95,55), y=c(17,14), z=c(45,76))

df
   x  y  z
1 95 17 45
2 55 14 76

chisq.test(df, correct = F)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  df
X-squared = 18.451, df = 2, p-value = 9.847e-05
```

Do you think the above way on three columns is correct? Can I apply chisq.test on three columns? Is it right or wrong? If not please help.

Comment: It's correct. See ?chisq.test

Comment: Another option to consider for your groups with low counts is the Fisher's Exact Test, see ?fisher.test